# Alternatives to encode URL

Tags: java, gwt, encoding

I am trying to encode input form data here. There are two options and I have tried both of them:

1. Use `URLencoder.encode(inputString)` method which does not work on GWT client side (My code resides in client module) Results in error 'Did you forget to inherit required module?'
2. `URL.encodeQueryString(inputString)` which works well, But when I run relevant test cases using JUnit, all I get is `unsatisfiedlinkederror`

Are there any alternatives for encoding method or is there any work around for above mentioned methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second option : 
GWT uses modules and needs to be compiled, which is different than running a simple JUnit test. Take a look at http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting.html, they explain how to setup JUnit test.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`URL`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html) class and its methods:

- [`URL.encode(String decodedURL)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`URL.encodeQueryString(String decodedURLComponent)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html#encodeQueryString%28java.lang.String%29)

Do not forget to inherit the required module `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP"/>`.

Comment: Yeah, I have already inherited this module in *.gwt.xml file. Still can't figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For URL building, I use the "UrlBuilder": com.google.gwt.http.client.UrlBuilder

```
UrlBuilder u = new UrlBuilder();
u.setProtocol("https");
u.setHost("www.mysite.com:8080");
u.setPath("/myServletPath");
u.setParameter("username", nameField.getValue());
u.setParameter("someAttribute", "itsValue");
u.buildString();
```

This code will result in:
https://www.mysite.com:8080/myServlet?username=GWT%20User&someAttribute=itsValue

Comment: It seems that UrlBuilder uses URL.encodeQueryString() internally to encode a given string. When I tried with it,it threw the same error 'UnsatisfiedLinkError due to URL.EncodeImpl'

Comment: Hi @Jayesh, the `com.google.gwt.http.client.UrlBuilder` is for use with GWT's client side. I also use it in my GWT project's client side, and can confirm it works. [I did some research](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/TtO-22bN7dA/discussion), and it seems `UnsatisfiedLinkError` happens when you call it from the server side. Please look at the stack trace for your error and make sure it's not being called from the server side.

Comment: Problem is one of my modules where I am using this function resides on server side. That is the reason I cannot make any transition from client to server side. Same with URLEncoder.encode() function rovided by Java. It is built to work on server side.When I use this function on client side, it says, 'did you forget to inherit required module?' though I am adding all necessary dependencies in the *.gwt.xml file.

Comment: Your original question was asking for what to use on the client side. Please clarify whether you need to encode a URL on the client side, or on the server side. For the client side, which gets compiled into JavaScript, you should use `com.google.gwt.http.client.UrlBuilder`. That class is compatible with JavaScript. On the server side, which works purely in Java, use `java.net.UrlEncoder` or `java.net.URL`.

Comment: Apology for the confusion. My code resides on client side and this is the reason I cannot use java.net.UrlEncoder or java.net.URL.        Now, I am using 'com.google.gwt.http.client.URL' to encode a string in the code which lies on client side(This works fine!).     However, when I try to run JUnit test cases which again execute the function 'URL.encodeQueryString()' , it throws an 'unsatisfiedlinkederror' since this function uses native function written in JavaScript to encode input string. Since it can not find any native JavaScript code in the library, it throws this error.